# repair windows search index one folder at a time? (without rebuilding everything)

Tags: windows-10, search

windows (10) search works nicely, but there are a couple of folders where I know search results should exist (DOC/PDF file contents), and they are not found

one solution is to rebuild everything, but that's wasteful, if only 1-2 folders need to be repaired.

Is there a way to refresh the search index only for the folders I tell it to?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 Search files are here (assuming the location was not changed):

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows

The main file is a database (of course), so you must rebuild the main index if it has been corrupted or damaged in any way.

Normal changes to the index happen incrementally and very quickly.

> Is there a way to refresh the search index only for the folders I tell
> it to?

No, that cannot be done.

Comment: thanks for the bad news :) I tried to remove then re-insert the folder from the index, but that didn't achieve much. I'll see if I can do it programmatically

Comment: I am not sure if you can alter the index DB safety. Make a backup or be prepared to delete and re-index if that does not work.

Comment: I don't claim it is 100% possible, but I'll have a go at it and if successful I'll blog about it :)